# Pivot entire dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to pivot the entire dataframe, using certain columns as values.

Data

```
id  date    sun moon    stars   total   ppp base    final   final2
aa  Q1 21   5   1       2       8       0   200     41      5
aa  Q2 21   4   1       2       7       1   200     50      6
```

Desired

```
id  date    type    ppp base    final   final2
aa  Q1 21   sun     0   200     41      5
aa  Q1 21   moon    0   200     41      5
aa  Q1 21   stars   0   200     41      5
aa  Q2 21   sun     1   200     50      6
aa  Q2 21   moon    1   200     50      6
aa  Q2 21   stars   1   200     50      6
```

Doing

```
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
```

(sample code)

I believe I have to perform something similar to this, but not exactly sure how to arrange this. I am still researching, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `df.drop(columns='total').melt(['id','date','final','final2','base','ppp'],var_name='type',value_name='ppp')`

Comment: Yes @AnuragDabas I will try this . The melt function is creating a long dataset I believe